# How to fix AVCapturevideopreviewlayer being smaller than actual camera view

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I'm working on an app that periodically takes pictures as part of a research job but I'm new to OOP and swift and am a little confused on what can cause this issue. I think it's because the UIView's size is smaller than the camera view size and it's getting cut out when displaying and I'm not sure how to program it to adapt to the UIView's dimensions. Here's my code:
[Video Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19Ok.jpg)        [Captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L22D.jpg)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //Creates session between camera input and data output
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
    var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var cameraCaptureOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    
    //Connects between this code document and Story Board
    @IBOutlet weak var Time: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Start: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var CameraView: UIView!


   //Misc Variables
    var alert: UIAlertController!
    var sPhoto : UIImage?
    var completionHandler : ((UIImage?) -> Void)?
    var timerCount:Bool  = false
    var timer:Timer = Timer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        initializeCaptureSession()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //assigns delegates to self
        Time.delegate = self
    }
    //Brings down Time keypad when any area other than keypad is touched
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        Time.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func initializeCaptureSession(){
        //Set's sessions presets
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        //Initalize Camera
        camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        
        do{
            if(camera == nil){
                print("No Camera Detected")
            }
            else{
            let cameraCaptureInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
            //Set's Camera Output
            cameraCaptureOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            session.addInput(cameraCaptureInput)
            session.addOutput(cameraCaptureOutput!)
            }
        } catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        let rootLayer: CALayer = self.CameraView.layer
        rootLayer.masksToBounds=false
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = rootLayer.bounds
        rootLayer.addSublayer(self.cameraPreviewLayer!)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        session.startRunning()
    }
    //Function that creates alert that dismisses
    func notifyUser(message: String) -> Void
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
          present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [unowned self] in
           self.dismiss(animated: true)
          }
    }
    
    @IBAction func StartPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if(Time.text!.isEmpty == true){
            notifyUser(message: "Please enter a interval")
        }
        else{
            if(timerCount){
                  timerCount = false
                  Start.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
                  Start.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                  timer.invalidate()
              }
            else{
                timerCount = true
                Start.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
                Start.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: Double(Time.text!)!, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
                      self?.takePicture()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func takePicture() {
        notifyUser(message: "Image Captured")
        //This is where you declare settings for the camera
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        settings.flashMode = .auto
        //Actually takes the photo
        cameraCaptureOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }
}

//Extensions
extension SecondViewController : UITextFieldDelegate{
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

extension SecondViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        //If photo failed to be captured
        guard error == nil else{
            print("Failed to capture photo")
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }
        //If pixel buffer could not be converted to image data
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            print("Fail to convert image data to UIImage")
            return
        }
        //If the UIImage could not be initalized with image data
        guard let capturedImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData, scale: 1.0) else{
            print("fail to convert image data to UIImage")
            return
        }
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, nil, nil, nil)
        //displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto: imageToSave)
    }
}
```

I've seen on other posts that the AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill has fixed it for some users so any explanations as to why that's not working would be extremely helpful - Much thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do you need so many lines of code to set the frame size of 'cameraPreviewLayer'?

Comment: And where does 'cameraPreviewLayer' come from anyway?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer

Comment: @ElTomato, that's part of the code that I don't completely understand but cora's link is clarifying my confusion. CameraPreviewLayer is declared at the top of all my code but isn't included in the post, I'll edit it to show where it came from.

Comment: Try the following.  let cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session);
cameraPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect;
self.view.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer)

Comment: I don't know which is the correct one, `resizeAspect` or `resizeAspectFill`.

Comment: @ElTomato I tried both and the camera view escaped the UIView's dimensions. I hope the images I edited into the post help clarify the problem